# Can't upload package to PyPI anymore

Tags: python, upload, package, pypi

I'm trying to upload a package (https://github.com/chembl/standardiser) to PyPI, the thing I done many times without any problems.

I use conda environment with Python 2.7.13 installed.

**1. First attempt:**

```
    python setup.py sdist upload
```

Error:

```
Submitting dist/standardiser-0.1.9.tar.gz to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (410): Gone (This API has been deprecated and removed from legacy PyPI in favor of using the APIs available in the new PyPI.org implementation of PyPI (located at https://pypi.org/). For more information about migrating your use of this API to PyPI.org, please see https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading. For more information about the sunsetting of this API, please see https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html)
error: Upload failed (410): Gone (This API has been deprecated and removed from legacy PyPI in favor of using the APIs available in the new PyPI.org implementation of PyPI (located at https://pypi.org/). For more information about migrating your use of this API to PyPI.org, please see https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading. For more information about the sunsetting of this API, please see https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2017-June/030766.html)
```

**2. Second attempt:**

```
    python setup.py sdist upload -r https://www.python.org.pypi
```

Error:

```
error: <urlopen error [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known>
```

**3. Third attempt systemwide Python 2.7.3:**

```
    python setup.py sdist upload

Error:

    Creating tar archive
    removing 'standardiser-0.1.9' (and everything under it)
    running upload
    Submitting dist/stardiser-0.1.9.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy
    error: None
```

The package is still not in PyPI

**4. Fourth attempt**

Creating a `~/.pypirc` file as descibed in https://packaging.python.org/guides/migrating-to-pypi-org/#uploading

```
     [distutils]
     index-servers =
       pypi

     [pypi]
     repository:https://pypi.python.org/pypi
     username:MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME
     password:MY_ACTUAL_PASSWORD
```

and running:

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

Error: the same as in 1.

**5. Fifth attempt**

Removing the `repository:https://pypi.python.org/pypi` line from `~/.pypirc`

and running:

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

Error: the same as in 1.

**6. Sixth attempt**

Legacy `~/.pypirc`

```
    [distutils]
    index-servers =
    pypi

    [pypi]
    repository: https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
    username: MY_ACTUAL_USERNAME
    password: MY_ACTUAL_PASSWORD
```

and running:

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

Error: the same as in 1.

Any other hints how can I upload my package to PyPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the upload command is not supported anymore by Pypi API ...

If you want to upload your project to Pypi use Twine.
The documentation is available here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/twine

Comment: You're welcome ! Pypi need to update their documentation regarding this point ...